# Why does Chrome fullscreen make the background black?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fullscreen

I built a web page with full screen functionality.  I used all of the right CSS properties to ensure that my gradient background fully covers the screen, and it does.  However, when I click the full screen button on the website in Chrome, the page goes to full screen but *the background turns to black*.  I looked everywhere and still can’t find anything wrong.  iPadOS seems to work fine.  The CSS is below, and the rest of the code is in my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/micahlt/pi-day).

Any help is much appreciated!

CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sen:wght@700&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 50vh;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #19c9ff 0%, #d504f9 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #19c9ff 0%,#d504f9 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #19c9ff 0%,#d504f9 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Sen', serif;
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.full {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 12px;
  font-size: 1.34em;
}

.auto {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 12px;
  font-size: 1.34em;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50vw;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

#pis {
  margin-top: 33vh;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.micah-box i {
  font-size: 2em !important;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.micah-box {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.micah:hover {
  color: white;
}

.micah-box h2 {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.3);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.micah-box h2:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: are github pages set up? Please provide a direct link so that one can quickly reproduce the issue

Comment: @YakovL you can view it on my website, https://micahlindley.com/pi-day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your fullscreen Javascript is slightly wrong.

```
body.requestFullscreen();
```

What your saying here is fullscreen the body element, and not the full page.

Instead try ->

```
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()
```

Comment: Oh, okay!  Thanks a lot!  That does make a lot more sense.  Accepted answer!